# How can I sync my iPhone to a new computer without erasing?

Tags: iphone, sync

I want to charge my iPhone, but it wants me to erase everything when I plug it into the USB of a new computer.  Is there a way to add it to a new computer and keep my data on the iPhone?

Comment: Phone questions are off topic. Please read the FAQ at the top of the page.

Comment: @Mark ".. except insofar as they interface with your computer"

Comment: @Sathya - Questions about phones, whether they interface with your computer or not, have been closed time and again on here as off-topic. If you disagree with this, you might want to bring it up on http://meta.stackoverflow.com but until then, they will continue to be closed.

Comment: @MarkM: Sathya's right.  questions about syncing a phone with a computer are the exception.  from the faq: "electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, **except insofar as they interface with your computer"**.  this question is ontopic, although it might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your itunes before plugging in your iPhone then if you're on Windows go to

> Edit -> Settings

Otherwise if you're on a Mac go to

> Preferences -> Devices

Click on the `Devices` tab then tick

> Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically

That should do the trick

[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix anything at all. I still can't sync to my other computer without being prompted that my device will be erased.

Comment: you can't sync on different computers without having your device erased, but you can plug it in and not have it sync automatically so you can either charge it or use it has a hard drive